# Update buttons-group checked state according to value in controller

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have buttons-group as filter like the following snapshot:

[image]

after selecting one, I update my filter object by calling a controller action.
The problem is, when I reload the page my buttons-group in view come back to initial state.

I'm new in web app programming, I don't know if I should use a html helper to linking the html components with filter model, or simply use a javascript onload event to populate my buttons-group. I already tested the last one but it doesn't work.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("element2").checked = true;
}
```

```html
<div id="session_group" class="filter-group">
  <label for="session_group" class="control-label col-sm-3">Session&nbsp;</label>
  <div class="btn-group user_toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-info active">
                <input type="radio" name="session_group_btn" id="element1" value="All" autocomplete="off">All
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-info">
                <input type="radio" name="session_group_btn" id="element2" value="1" autocomplete="off">Automne
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-info">
                <input type="radio" name="session_group_btn" id="element3" value="2" autocomplete="off">Automne A
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-info">
                <input type="radio" name="session_group_btn" id="element4" value="3" autocomplete="off">Été
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-info">
                <input type="radio" name="session_group_btn" id="element5" value="4" autocomplete="off">Été A
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-info">
                <input type="radio" name="session_group_btn" id="element6" value="5" autocomplete="off">Printemps
            </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-info">
                <input type="radio" name="session_group_btn" id="element7" value="6" autocomplete="off">Printemps/Été
            </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually enable a button in the group, you need to use the Bootstrap button's toggle method `$().button('toggle')`

```
$(document).ready(function{

    // Toggles push state. Gives the button the appearance that it has been activated.
    $("#element2").parent().button('toggle');

});
```

Reference Link:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

Comment: Thanks, I would like to find element by value and then toggle it, how I can do that ?

Comment: Yes ! $('input[name="session_group_btn"]').filter(function () { return this.value =='1' }).parent().button('toggle'); Thank you @Vishnu